# In Monaco Editor, how to get the actual value from a Token?

Tags: javascript, tokenize, monaco-editor

I used monaco.editor.tokenize and received a result of token[][].

`var tokens = monaco.editor.tokenize(text, "myLanguage");`

I but the token only contains properties of language, offset and type. I would like to know how can I get the actual value of each token? Or is there any other ways of find the values of tokenized tokens?

I looked around the documentaiton of Monaco but I don't find any way that will help.

Answer (score 1):

Each token entry has an offset member, so you can get its position and its length (by subtracting the offset of this token from that of the following token). Use that with the original text to get a substring as token text.

Comment: But token does not have length property.

Comment: @skymanlee you can calculate its length by subtracting offset of the previous token, as said in the answer. If this token is the first one in the line then its length equals to its offset.

Comment: @llesha Thanks for the reply. But technically to say, there could be some characters not tokenized between 2 tokens. So "subtracting the offset of this token from that of the following token" could contain some extra values that are not same as what the tokenizer parsed. Isn't it?

Comment: @skymanlee Yes, I didn't think about that. Well, you can get a substring between two offsets, and if untokenized part is the whitespace, you can remove it with js. 

If some of your characters are not whitespace and are untokenized, there is a way to create an "invalid" token and assign it to `@default` branch in tokenization cases. But that's not the ideal solution of course. If you need info on tokenization cases I can provide it.